# What is the 'Real' Definition of a PORT? Where are they installed?

Tags: networking, port

I am confused the concept of a PORT in Networking.

But am not clear with where do they exist?
My Queries...

1. > Where do they reside?
2. > Can I change them?
3. > How does the ISP blocks a Port(I have read in some articles where ISPs block certain ports numbers of a tenant and so tenant is not able to host a website)
4. > If port number is blocked inside a Router, how is it done?
5. > Who has reserved certain Port Numbers for Web, SMTP, FTP, etc.

A definition for the dumb will go for me.

Comment: [TCP-IP Ports and how they work](http://www.bullguard.com/bullguard-security-center/pc-security/computer-security-resources/tcp-ip-ports.aspx)

Comment: [Port (computer networking)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29)

Comment: How can you know the definition but not know what they are?

Comment: @ScottHunter well, you could memorize the definition and not understand what you have memorized! like E=M C^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Are they only used to specify "which application should use the data? "
```

yeah I think so. Or a process rather than an application.  A process is an instance of an application in memory.

And the port is one field of many fields within a packet(to use a general and  useful definition of packet).

When a process is said to listen on a particular port X, it means it is reading or being given packets that have port set to X

Say you have two computers A and B

B has a bunch of different pieces of software, different processes running

each process on A and each process on B associates with ports.. And so when packets go to A or B, the processes know which packets are for them.

In fact it's not just for each process..  It's for a communication channel.. So a process on A wants to exchange data with a process on B.  So A picks a port for that communication, and B picks a port for that communication.. And A and B send packets to each other with the source and destination ports set correctly.

If A and B want to communicate on another subject or a related subject, or the user on A or user on B want to.. Then they can use new ports. And so the programs on A and B  or users on A and B , can see the two communication channels separately by looking at all packets where the source or destination port is X.

As to your questions

> Where do they reside?

Say you have Computer A and Computer B,  then Computer A is said to have a port open, and computer B is said to have a port open.  It's like an ID, the program would "open a port", i.e. it'd request from the OS that a "port" be set aside for its use.

> Can I change them?

There are two cases of a port opening..i.e. a port coming into existence.  That ID being created for use.

One is when a program initiates a connection, and the other is when a program is listening for a connection.  The listening happens first.

When it comes to making a program listen for a connection, you can often tell the program which port to listen on. Usually the program will give you the option.

You can try this yourself by setting up what is called a "server".. There are different definitions of server..  One is a rather powerful computer, another is a central computer that might be accessed by many others, or even be used to access many others.   And another definition  - the main definition - is a piece of software that listens for others to connect (often potentially many others to connect), so you see other definitions of server spring from that one.

You can create a server.. set one up

Tinyweb is a little web server

Instructions are on this website

https://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/tinyweb/install.php

so create c:\blah\index.html  it can even be blank.

this makes it listen on port 8000

```
Run TinyWeb on port 8000:
c:\tinyweb\tiny.exe c:\blah 8000
```

You can then do http://127.0.0.1:8000     So accessing your computer's local (virtual I guess) network interface 127.0.0.1   The so-called loopback interface
And specifying port 8000

If you set up tinyweb on a different port, then you would http to a different port, changing the number after the colon

and view your webpage

Typically people have web servers listen on port 80.. if they're public.. And sometimes port 8080 if they're internal to their own LAN and not public.

Load of programs listen on a port.  VNC for example, that is a program that lets you view your computer remotely. It has settings where you specify a port

[image]

There is a program called nc that can just listen on a port and output whatever is sent to it. You can run that with cygwin if you install cygwin.

So, The program itself can change which port it listens on.  and you can tell the program..

That's for servers, programs that listen on a port

Programs that initiate a connection with the server, are called client programs. You always have a client and a server..  One program that listens (normally called the client) and one program that listens (normally called the server).

Client and server can mean the client requests and the server replies.. and then if the one that replies is the client then you can get some funny terminology from some software about a server making a reverse connection.. to a client. But normally the one that initiates is called a client and the one that listens is called the server, and normally it's also the client that makes the requests and the server making the replies. e.g. your web browser is a client and it requests webpages from the web server at some remote IP.

Clients , i.e. programs initiating connections, they get a random port number above 1024

If you open cmd.exe and run  `netstat -aon` then you see a list of connections including ports.  It shows local port and remote port for any connection.

So look for the port numbers < 1024. Here we have a server listening on port 1234 on my computer (0.0.0.0 means any IP can connect.. though that could be stopped by a firewall, or NAPT router).

And the other line look in the foreign address you see port 80.. that's my computer connecting to a web server

The ports > 1023  are random ports

The first 1024 ports ports 0-1023 are generally the ones that servers use. though sometimes people choose higher ports for servers, as a layer of security, to hide a little bit better to make detection a little bit harder from a hacker. Or out of a convention like 8080 for an internal web server on a LAN.

```
C:\>netstat -aon

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1234           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3656
  ...
  TCP    10.0.0.92:50735        147.148.112.39:80      CLOSE_WAIT      5340


How does the ISP blocks a Port(I have read in some articles where ISPs block certain ports numbers of a tenant and so tenant is not able to host a website)
```

> ```
> If port number is blocked inside a Router, how is it done?
> ```

NAT Routers do it.  Though they can run a firewall too and that can do it too

NAT routers are doing a form of NAT with many names including NAPT or NAT/PAT. To unblock it on a NAT router, you'd do "port forwarding". which means that when a request is made and comes across from outside typically the internet, to connect to your server, the router passes it onto one of your computers, the one you tell it to, that runs the server.

The software they'd use is called a firewall. You run one too in Windows XP and Windows 7. There are also dedicated hardware firewalls (they also run firewall software)

> ```
> Who has reserved certain Port Numbers for Web, SMTP, FTP, etc.
> ```

They are conventions

IANA I suppose. And they have a list of them all.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt

Comment: Thanks for your Response @barlop. I have edited the question. Can you help updating me?

Comment: @karanSingh ok that's updated

Answer (score 1):

Think of Ports as traffic lanes dedicated for a specific type/class of vehicle. If you are driving a car, you can drive only on the lane meant for Cars.

Similarly, on a network, Ports & the associated firewall rules dictate what application/protocol can communicate through a certain port on the network. For instance, port 80 is used by HTTP, 20 and 21 are used by FTP etc...

When your friend says "Port 80 is blocked by his ISP" - it could be to prevent him from browsing the webpages on his connection. These days, ISPs (especially mobile data providers) offer Internet Data packs which allow access only for certain applications (like Whatsapp, Facebook etc...), in which case they would block access to all ports except the ones which are required by Whatsapp, Facebook or the app for which user has paid for.